# Powershell Error “The term 'Get-Spsite' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function…”

Tags: powershell

I just typed the follow to try and get my SharePoint site:

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity $siteID
```

And I get the following error message:

```
The term 'Get-SPSite' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script..
```

So after some searches, Apparenty I have to add the following line:

```
Add-PSSnap in Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
```

but when I run it, I get the following message:
Add-PSSnapin: No snap-ins have been registered for Windows Powershell version 5

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you for help :)

Comment: https://www.google.se/amp/s/learn-powershell.net/2012/06/28/run-powershell-in-version-2-while-powershell-v3-rc-is-installed/amp/

Comment: You need to change the powershell version.

Comment: are you running the powershell on the SharePoint server or pc / laptop

Comment: I'm working on the SP server

Comment: If SharePoint install on it, then open the SharePoint PowerShell window? unless you are using the windows powershell ISE?

Answer (score 3):

Invalid syntax: `Add-PSSnap in Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell`

Use:

```
if(!(Get-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue))
{ 
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell 
}
```

Please make sure that you run the PowerShell on a SharePoint Server machine.

The PowerShell script below can get a list of snap-ins that are registered on your computer:

```
Get-PSSnapin –registered
```

More information about 
[Add-PSSnapin](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Add-PSSnapin?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer
But I have the same error message:
Add-PsSnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 5.

Comment: get-pssnapin –registered https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Add-PSSnapin?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: get-pssnapin returns:
Name: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core
PsVersion :5.1.14393.2636
Description: This windows Powershell snap-im contains cmdlets  used to manage components of Windows Powershell

get-pssnapin-Registered returns nothing

Comment: https://powershell.org/forums/topic/pssnapin-question-and-onenote/